# google firebase function tutorial unexpected token =>

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have done some googling and haven't found an answer to my question. I am following the tutorial for google firebase functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0) and have copied `index.js` exactly from the GitHub repository linked on the tutorial as well as copying the code in 'chunks' by following the tutorial and I get this error after running `firebase deploy --only functions`

`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>`

which references this function:

```
exports.addMessage = (functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => { //This line
    // [END addMessageTrigger]
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    // [START adminSdkAdd]
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({ original: original });
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.` });
    // [END adminSdkAdd]
}));
```

[Link to index.js file used in tutorial](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/466eb2aca56d4317cc0ae9079469add8294ab6f9/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js#L29-L42)

My `eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you using ESLint? If yes can you share it's config?

Comment: I have eslint installed as an extension on vscode, how can I share the config?

Comment: There must be a config file either js or json. `.elint` or similar

Comment: I have added `ESLint.rc` to the original post

Comment: Can you please try adding `parserOptions: {ecmaVersion: 8}` in that object?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thank you this worked. If you add that as an answer I will accept it. Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked. Sure just give me a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions and await keyword were added in ECMAScript 2017. You need to set `ecmaVersion` to `8` in your ESLint config.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 8
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```