# Delete Folder inside Firebase Storage with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to create a Cloud Function that when an Object (Listing) is deleted in Firestore, it automatically deletes the images associated in FirebaseStorage.

As Context, when a Listing is created we take that Document Id and set it as the name of a subfolder in FirebaseStorage.

Like this:

[image: Folder Structure]

So basically I have the Main Bucket inside a Folder Call ListingImages and Inside per Listing (document in Firestore), there is a Folder.

So my end goal is that when I delete the document with that ID in my Firestore, it deletes the Folder in Firebase Storage and all its content.

Currently, I have this Cloud Function Code but it doesn't work:

```
// Function que elimina imagenes de un Listing cuando es borrado de Firebase.
exports.listingImagesDelete = functions.firestore.document("listings/{listingId}").onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
  const listingId = snapshot.id;

  const filePath = "ListingImages/" + listingId + "/";
  const defaultBucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const file = defaultBucket.file(filePath);
  const pr = file.delete();

  return pr;
});
```

But when I run it (Delete the listing from Firestore) it gives me this Error:

[image: Error on Function Running]

It looks as if there is no Object there, although there is a Folder.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [`@google-cloud/storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) module and setting the path prefix:

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage")

exports.listingImagesDelete = functions.firestore.document("listings/{listingId}").onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
  const listingId = snapshot.id;
  
  const storage = new Storage();

  const bucket = storage.bucket('name'); // [PROJECT_ID].appspot.com is default bucket
    
  return bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: `ListingImages/${listingId}`
  })
});
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to the code sample - while I got the description done first. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that was quick :D My emulators were starting and was about to post complete function 

Comment: Ah, this type of thing I usually copy the code from the docs or examples, as it's quite common (once you know you need to do a prefix delete).

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj and Frank just a question the line of:

const bucket = storage.bucket('name');

The name in there is any name or the domain given by Firebase storage the one that I hide, or anything else. Kind Regards.

Comment: @ReneAlas the default bucket name is `[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`. You can find it in the Firebase storage console.

Comment: final Issue and sorry, the => (arrow) is giving me a Lint error:

Parsing error: Unexpected token =>eslint
function(snapshot: functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext): Promise<void>

Comment: @ReneAlas yea that's ESLint. You can remove  `async` or checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451557/google-firebase-function-tutorial-unexpected-token/68451911#68451911) if you want to use async arrow function

Comment: Hey Sorry for the delay, it didn't give any errors, but at the end didn't delete the folder, on delete of the Listing Document.

Comment: Also it marks as unused the variable listingId inside the Function, any ideas?

Comment: @ReneAlas in my previous code I had used quotes instead of backticks. Try this: `prefix: "ListingImages/"+listingId` or use string interpolation as in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Folders are not a real thing on Cloud Storage. In reality it is just one long list of files, and having a `/` in the name/path of the file is interpreted as a folder (also referred to as a *prefix*, since it's the start of the name/path).

What this means in practice is that in order to delete a folder, you need to delete all files inside that folder. Once you do that, the folder will automatically disappear.